# VB Collection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, activex, catia

I've been serching the net for quite some time and maybe there is no solution for my problem but I hoped you might be able to help me. I'm currently trying to establish a connection to CatiaV5 via JavaScript. The connection itsself is working just fine. Basically it looks like this now:

```
var catia = new ActiveXObject('CATIA.Application');
var doc = catia.ActiveDocument;
```

But here's my problem. The returned object is a `Collection` in VB and there seems to be no `DataType` equivalent to this. So this is what i get when i try to read my variables. For example:

```
doc.Product
```

returns

```
[object] {};
```

So this seems to be empty. However if then I try to get

```
doc.Product.Name
```

which by that logic should be undefined, instead i get

```
"Part1"
```

so the correct name of my Part/Product is returned.

All the Catia stuff probably isn't that relevant for the question.

my question: Is there any way to somehow parse a `VB-Collection` on a `JavaScript` object or something similar, to get the contents of what is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

here's the thing. I found out, that you can't really browse throug ActiveXObjects directly in the console in general. In the IE-Dev-Tools i was however able to use the Locals-Watch to browse through the Object. I didn't find a nice way to Parse it onto a JSON-Object, however the manual way to create a new Object and add the Keys piece by piece works.